# How to calculate TTY-console size (how many characters) with given to display resolution (e.g. 480x320) and given font size (e.g. 14,15 or 16)?

Tags: tty, fonts, console, ncurses

I don't have this 3.5" display yet, so I couldn't just test it with `tput cols` and `tput lines`. I'd like to know how many characters fit in both axes, before I develop a software with curses.

Comment: use your smartphone to determine the desired text size for your 3.5" display ... cut a window in a piece of cardboard to match the size of the 3.5" display and place it on your phone ... don't forget that the text on the 3.5" display will not be as smooth as the smartphone display

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine the width and height of the font, assuming you’re using a monospaced font (where all glyphs occupy the same width). Then divide the number of horizontal pixels by the font width to calculate the number of text columns, and the number of vertical pixels by the font height to calculate the number of text rows.

With a VGA-style 8×16 font on a 480×320 screen, you’d get 60 columns and 20 rows.

Comment: I test on different display with (480x800 res) with few other font sizes.
======================================

    |A         |B |line |cols |A*C |B*D|

    |12 |6 |34 |96 |408 |576|
    |20 |10 |20 |57 |400 |570|
    |22 |11 |18 |52 |396 |572|
    |24 |12 |17 |48 |408 |576|
    |28 |14 |14 |41 |392 |574|

======================================
- A,B are the font sizes
- lines, cols are the output of (tput lines, and tput cols)
- A*C and B*D are multiplied corresponding column values.

It seems like, it's not simply dividing situation, is it?

Comment: AFAIK, it is division, integer division — so the result is rounded down to the nearest integer. Your results match a screen with something like 576×408 pixels; does that match anything in the specs?

Comment: I think that, the (unused) black border around the TTY-console taking few character spaces.